# Do we need to do anything with the "aosp" and "android-source" tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I already knew we had an [android-source](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-source) tag, but apparently we also have an [aosp](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aosp) tag (with AOSP being an acronym for Android Open Source Project, for anyone who might not be aware). This strikes me as kind of redundant, especially since the tag wiki for [android-source](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-source) explicitly uses the acronym "AOSP".

It seems to me that the [android-source](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-source) could actually be removed, since it largely serves as a tag for off-topic development questions (it seemed to crop up mostly after "android" was blacklisted). There are a couple of questions that actually do ask about Android's source code, but I don't see any reason why those few couldn't be retagged to use [aosp](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aosp) (still a perfectly valid tag for those questions, I think), and then the tags could be synonymized somehow or [android-source](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-source) could just be abandoned.

To expand a bit on what motivated this discussion/question: I've always thought [android-source](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-source) was just not a very useful tag. It **could** have potential use, I suppose, but most of the legitimate uses (in my opinion) would overlap with [aosp](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aosp). Discussion of Android's source code in a general sense feels out-of-scope for us, and so I'm not personally convinced that [android-source](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-source) really has a compelling use case from that angle.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[aosp](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aosp) seems to me to be a subset of [android-source](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-source).  For example, this question doesn't fit under [aosp](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aosp) : https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17108/webpage-with-amazon-kindle-source-code-summary-of-changes

That said, I do see the problem with it being used for dev questions.  For now I've removed it from those questions (and also deleted a bunch of old dev questions).

**Update:** I've removed both tags from all questions.

Comment: I went back and forth on that one, too, but part of me thinks that question is something of an anomaly WRT the tags we currently have. I'll also admit that I've always thought `[android-source]` was just not a very useful tag, though. Even on that question I'm tempted to just remove it and leave the KF tag as the only one, since it's not *really* about the Android source code in a general sense - it's about the KF's source code.

Comment: @eldarerathis That's a fair point. Let's see if anyone else has thoughts.

Comment: I've removed [android-source] from a few totally irrelevant questions that only had that tag this week, it does seem like it's being used simply because "Android" auto-completes to it, and people can't be bothered to think of any other tags to use. Would say it either needs to go, or be a synonym of [aosp]. Left on its own it's just too much of a tempatation for lazy taggers

Comment: Well, by itself, [tag:android-source] isn't very useful. If it stays it should be renamed [tag:android-source-code].